# Caching object in Application_AuthenticateRequest

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

Is there any user specific caching object available inside the Application_AuthenticateRequest? I've notice Session and Cache are not available. I'm using .net framework 3.5 and aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access what you want via:

```
HttpContext.Current
```

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Session is not set during Application_AuthenticateRequest.  HttpRuntime.Cache is application wide not user specific.  Does anyone know any alternatives?